# Facebook authentication not working with custom callback path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I'm using devise / omniauth to authenticate my Rails app against Facebook. I'm trying to change the `callback_path` to be something custom, but no matter what I set it to, the `omniauth.auth` request variable comes back as nil. For example, here I'm setting the `callback_path` to the exact value that it is if I don't set it:

```
Devise.setup do |config |    
  require "omniauth-facebook"
  config.omniauth :facebook, 
    ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], 
    ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'], 
    scope: "email",
    :setup => lambda { |env| 
       env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:callback_path] = "user/auth/facebook/callback"
    }
end
```

If I don't set the `:callback_path`, then authentication works and I get data back in the `omniauth.auth` request variable. But, I have to override it because I need to support passing an attribute back on the callback.

I've looked through the [Omniauth::Strategy code](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb) to see what might be going wrong, but I can't quite figure out what's going wrong.

My questions:

- Why is this not working?
- Is there a better way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `state` param is not supposed to be used to pass data (in fact, just think about it, you are trusting a 3rd party with your data!). That param is only to be used to mitigate CSRF attacks.

So what you should do, is pass any param you like to the link, like so:

```
link_to user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook, :some_key => 'some_data')
```

Omniauth will [automatically add that data to the session](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/blob/deea8f23642734217fc8a91cfe9a09a69595d638/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb#L200) and on the callback will [remove that data from the session](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/blob/deea8f23642734217fc8a91cfe9a09a69595d638/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb#L225), letting you access it like this:

```
request.env['omniauth.params']['some_key']
```

Comment: I did end up using the state to pass the variable, but I still don't understand why the callback_path can't be overridden. As per the documentation, that's exactly what it's supposed to be used for.

Comment: Indeed, I looked at the [Setup Phase Omniauth wiki](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Setup-Phase) and it seemed to match what you tried. Btw, did you also try `config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'], :callback_path => "user/auth/facebook/callback"`?